# PHP: Replace Array Data

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of associative array, I will like to update the values in this array, hence I created a function that looks like this.

```
//The Array of Associative arrays
 array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'slang' => string 'Tight' (length=5)
      'description' => string 'Means well done' (length=15)
      'example-sentence' => string 'Prosper it Tight on that job' (length=28)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'slang' => string 'Sleet' (length=5)
      'description' => string 'Means to send on long errand' (length=28)
      'example-sentence' => string 'I am going to sleep sia' (length=23)
```

//The function

```
public function update($slang, $new)
{
  array_map(function($data, $key) use($slang, $new)
  {
    if($data['slang'] == $slang)
    {
      $data[$key] = array_replace($data, $new);
    }
  }, UrbanWord::$data);
}
```

I tired running this but the original array will not update. I need help on how to go about fixing this please.

Thanks

Comment: Afaik, `array_map` returns an array with the mapped data. You don't seem to catch that return.

Comment: @Afaik, yes, thanks, fixed that still does not work

Comment: As much as I love `array_map`, if you want to replace array elements inline, a plain old `foreach` (or `array_walk`) is probably more appropriate here imho.

Comment: If you've sorted that, can you update your question's code, then please define doesn't work. Please provide the inputs (UrbanWord::$data, $slang and $new) the current output you're getting, and the expected output you want to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) instead of `array_map` as following:

```
public function update($array, $slang, $new)
{
  return array_reduce($array, function ($result, $item) use ($slang, $new) {
    if ($item['slang'] == $slang) {
       $item = array_replace($item, $new);
    }

    $result[] = $item;

    return $result;
  }, array());
}
```

Usage:

```
UrbanWord::$data = $this->update(
  UrbanWord::$data,
  'Tight',
  array('description' => 'another description')
);
var_dump($myUpdatedArray);
```

If you want to update it directly passing the `UrbanWord::$data` by reference you may try something like:

```
class UrbanWord
{
    public static $data = array(
        array(
            'slang' => 'Test',
            'Desc'  => 'Frist Desc'
        ),
        array(
            'slang' => 'Test1',
            'Desc'  => 'Second Desc'
        )
    );
}

class MyClass
{
    public function update(&$array, $slang, $new)
    {
        $array = array_reduce($array, function ($result, $item) use ($slang, $new) {
            if ($item['slang'] == $slang) {
                $item = array_replace($item, $new);
            }

            $result[] = $item;

            return $result;
        }, array());
    }
}

$myClass = new MyClass();
$myClass->update(UrbanWord::$data, 'Test', array('Desc' => 'test'));

echo '<pre>';
var_dump(UrbanWord::$data);
echo '</pre>';
```